# Anything wrong in my Producer-Consumer implementation in Python using condition objects?

Tags: python, multithreading

Can someone let me know what is wrong in my code below that implements the producer-consumer problem in python. I am using Python 3.4

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
import time

maxSize = 4    # maximum size of the queue
q = deque([])
cur = 0    # current value to push into the queue

lk = threading.Lock()
cvP = threading.Condition(lk)    # condition object for consumer
cvC = threading.Condition(lk)    # condition object for producer

class Producer:
    def run(self):
        global maxSize, q, cur
        while True:
            with cvP:
                while len(q) >= maxSize:
                    print( "Queue is full and size = ", len(q) )
                    cvC.notify()   # notify the Consumer
                    cvP.wait()    # put Producer to wait

                q.append(cur)
                print("Produced ", cur)
                cur = cur + 1
                cvC.notify()    # notify the Consumer


class Consumer:
    def run(self):
        global maxSize, q, cur
        while True:
            with cvC:
                while len(q) == 0:
                    print( "Queue is empty and size = ", len(q) )
                    cvP.notify()  # notify the Producer
                    cvC.wait()    # put Consumer to wait

                x = q.popleft()
                print("Consumed ", x)
                time.sleep(1)
                cvP.notify()    # notify the Producer

p = Producer()
c = Consumer()
pThread = Thread( target=p.run(), args=())
cThread = Thread( target=c.run(), args=())
pThread.start()
cThread.start()
pThread.join()
cThread.join()
```

The program output:

```
Produced  0
Produced  1
Produced  2
Produced  3
Queue is full and size =  4
```

Then it got stuck. When terminating the program, I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/t.py", line 47, in <module>
    pThread = Thread( target=p.run(), args=())
  File "path/t.py", line 22, in run
    cvP.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 289, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The Producer seemed not "nofity" the consumer. Can someone let me know why?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you never release the lock from in the producer code. (This is from my experience with C condition variables so it may be different in Python).

Comment: For the Producer: on waiting, the lock will be released by cvP.wait(); after successfully producing, the lock will be released at the exit of "with cvP", i.e., after cvC.notify(). This is my understanding. I am also new to Python.

Comment: It's been a while since I took my multithreading OS course, but shouldn't the while checks be if statements instead? I don't see a reason to use "while(len(q) == 0)" over "if (len(q) == 0)" since you're already waiting inside the while loop. When it gets notified/woken up, the condition should be already fulfilled.

Comment: @user3085290 to be stable with multiple producers and consumers.

Comment: @GuohuaLiu on saying `cvP.notify()` after consuming one item in `Consumer()`, what s the advantage of awakening producer, until you release lock?

Answer (score 6):

The locking and unlocking are fine, but you probably want to specify 'run' as the target and not 'run()'

```
pThread = Thread( target=p.run, args=())
cThread = Thread( target=c.run, args=())
```

:-)

Explanation: lets simplify

```
def foo():
  # ..

# Foo will run on a new thread
Thread(target=foo)

# foo() is run before the thread is created, and its return
# value is the target for the Thread call.
Thread(target=foo())
```

You can see in the stack trace that it never went beyond line 47, which is

```
pThread = Thread( target=p.run(), args=())
```

Which is the same as

```
x = p.run()
pThread = Thread(x, args=())
```

Comment: You are great orip! It worked fine after removing the parenthesis. Can you explain a bit on why this syntax issue cause the running problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: @GuohuaLiu - if it helped don't forget to accept the answer :-D